# Converting tracker pose information into column-major ordered matrix

Tags: opengl

I have a text file consisting of the poses of an object that is tracked by a tracker. The format of the lines in the text file are as follows:

```
   Tx  Ty  Tz  R11  R12  R13  R21  R22  R23  R31  R32  R33
```

The standard way to construct a `4x4` transformation matrix from the rotation and translation values is:

```
   | R11  R12  R13  Tx |
   | R21  R22  R23  Ty |
   | R31  R32  R33  Tz |
   |  0    0    0    1 |
```

I want to use the transformation matrix from my tracker in OpenGL, which requires data to be stored in column-major order. I am confused by the ordering of this matrix in memory in OpenGL. Is it supposed to be ordered as a 16-element array in `C++` as shown below, and then passed to `glMultMatrixf()`? Or is there some other way of ordering?

```
   | {R11  R21  R31  0}  {R12  R22  R32  0}  {R13  R23  R33  0}  {Tx  Ty  Tz  1} |
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I confirmed that the data should be stored in memory in the column-major format as described below:

```
    | {R11  R21  R31  0}  {R12  R22  R32  0}  {R13  R23  R33  0}  {Tx  Ty  Tz  1} |
```

I tested this by acquiring tracker poses in known orientations, and rendering the poses as planes in OpenGL.